# Couldn't able to find header files under frame work in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

I added a framework to the project, while compiling error was coming like framework not found . In project navigator under the framework I couldn't able to see any header files . I tried adding the frame work in build phase and tried adding the path in search framework path and header path but of no luck still coming the same issue .